# What are the academic career prospects for someone in their late 30's starting a PhD?

Tags: phd, united-states, career-path, age

I'm in my late 30's and started a Ph.D. program and am wondering what my academic career prospects are. From my understanding, after the Ph.D., there are 2-3 years of postdoc, then 4-6 years of tenure-track before becoming a Prof. Is that correct?

My field is `machine learning` (or `artificial intelligence`) and I'm in the US.

Comment: Broadly speaking, can you tell us what field you are in?  In my experience this can vary pretty widely.

Comment: Updated the question with relevant information

Comment: Also Shamoon, similar to Jeff's response - what country is this you are referring to? There might be different expectaions/oppertunities relevant to your location

Comment: Updated with the country as well.

Comment: If you work hard and get extremely lucky on the job market, that's what your career could look like. In practice, you may need to spend 5+ years as a postdoc, and even then that's no guarantee of landing a tenure-track or permanent job.

Comment: @astronaut I don't believe that's true at all for data science and machine learning.  But maybe turn your response into an answer?

Comment: What are the academic career prospects for anyone!?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the answer here is that it depends on a lot of factors, but that you'll generally do better in the Machine Learning field than you would in many of the older, more established fields.

For starters, there's just not that many people out there with PhDs in Machine Learning.  I'm an economist, but I've spent a lot of time working around the edges of machine learning and data science.  Many of the faculty in that area have degrees in different but related fields.  Econ, stats, math, and computer science are common.

Machine learning is also an incredibly hot field right now.  Before I went back to academia I worked in applied research, and finding an experienced person with a "data scientist" title in their job history was a nightmare.  Private sector jobs are common, and the salaries are high, which pulls people away from academia.

**So while being an older graduate hitting the job market may be a challenge in academia, I think the shortage of talent available in this field will offset it.**  Especially if you have relevant work experience in data science, research, and/or machine learning from before now.

On a side note, unless your goal is specifically to do PhD research (i.e. are you interested in applying ML in teaching or research, or are you interested in working on the mathematical underpinnings?) in the field and earn tenure, you can accomplish a lot, even in academia, with a master's degree in this field.  Might be something to explore if you decide not to go the whole way.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on “you can accomplish a lot, even in academia, with a master’s degree”?

Comment: Just as university examples personally known to me, people with MAs are full-time lecturers, and program directors in this field.

Comment: Why is being an older graduate unquestionably a challenge in the academic job market?

Comment: I cannot speak for @Jeff, but I would say two practical impediments are older graduates being more likely to face two-body or other familial constraints, and general physical decline, particularly dealing with fatigue.  And that's ignoring the challenges of outright age discrimination on behalf of hiring committees.

Comment: It's good to hear others don't think age is an issue.  That hasn't matched my experience, but I edited it to say "may".

Comment: @Jeff I wasn't being rhetorical. I was asking why you think the job market would be worse for older graduates.

Answer (score 6):

A slightly utopian answer, but I’ll wait for all the naysayers out there to correct me if they want to:

**Your academic career prospects as a beginning graduate student in your late 30’s are the same as they would be for a beginning graduate student of any other age group.**

If you are talented and work hard, you will succeed. Don’t overthink this.

In addition to that, your area is super trendy and I’m hearing about a lot of hiring activity currently going on in this and related areas (anything that falls under the label of data science). So your prospects seem generally good, both in academia and (perhaps even more so) in industry.

Good luck!

Comment: Minor quibble: If you are talented *and* you work hard...

Comment: It's a nice hypothesis, but it's not backed up by evidence and I would venture the guess that it's wrong.

Comment: Kinda sad that complying with the law and basic ethics would be considered utopian.

Comment: @ElizabethHenning I never mentioned law and ethics. But yes, in general I agree it would be better if I could post the same answer without feeling like I ought to qualify it as slightly utopian.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth well, I personally know some successful academics who started their careers late. But you are correct that this is more based on personal opinion than on hard statistical data. Anyway, if you have evidence for your guess to the contrary, please share it.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth I guess by “evidence” you mean something like “empirically, there aren't many late-starting PhDs who go on to become very successfull”. But may that not well be mere correlation? Surely, most _talented researchers_ quickly go from undergraduate to PhD, so that would be why you don't find many of them amongst old PhDs. But this doesn't imply that any given one of those couldn't still become succesfull if they had their PhD delayed for a decade by force majeure.

Comment: Major quibble: If you are talented _and_ you work hard _and_ you're lucky _and_ you have the right connections _and_ your area of research is popular, you will succeed. Academia is extremely competitive, and there are far more people going after academia positions than there are academic positions. Believing that things will magically work out if you're talented and work hard is simply delusional, on the order of the just-world fallacy.

Comment: @DanRomik: I don't have any evidence either, just a gut feeling. Part of it may be that it's uncommon in STEM fields for people to go back to grad school after a few years elsewhere, and uncommon rarely leads to (statistically speaking) higher success rates -- some exceptions notwithstanding, of course. (It's different in other fields: In adult education and human resource development, nearly every professor had a career before academia.)

Comment: @anomaly everything you say applies equally to young researchers. Yes, academia is very competitive, everyone here knows that. But OP’s question, and my answer, was about the _difference_ in the ability to succeed between younger and older researchers. So I stand by my remark. Your major quibble, while true, is not any more true in the context of OP’s question than it is in a generic context (and in fact it’s less true for machine learning PhDs, as I discuss in my answer), so doesn’t add much to the discussion IMHO.

Comment: @DanRomik: My objection is specifically to the comment that "If you are talented and work hard, you will succeed," which I don't think is useful advice to anyone, regardless of age, and doesn't fit the specific situation of the OP.  The career prospects for anyone in academia are bad. The career prospects for someone in industry in ML are quite good; but if the OP is interested in academia, it's possible--- though unlikely--- to jump from industry to academia in ML; in other fields, it's a total nonstarter.

Comment: @anomaly ok, as long as we’re clear that your position is that my advice is bad advice for _anyone_ and not just for OP, I am happy. :-)

Comment: @DanRomik: Ha! :)

Comment: This is definitely utopian, and completely untrue in the real world.  If you start 15 years late, you've lost 15 years, and nothing will get those years back for you.  Instead of happening at a typical 40, tenure probably won't happen until 55.  The career prospects are absolutely different for someone starting late.  OP would be a fool to ignore those very real circumstances.  That's not to dissuade them, but it's disingenuous to pretend that it's like they can start their life over at 22 years old again.

Comment: @J... You could also have your career shortened  by cancer or numerous other events. This doesn't address the OP's question. Why would *prospects* be worse for an older graduate?

Comment: @ElizabethHenning Prospect = probability for future success.  If there is less future, the cumulative probability of successes goes down.  Consider OP having started their career at 22 versus 15 years later.  Do you believe on their 50th birthday that these two hypothetical futures have equal probability of achieving the same level of progress?  It doesn't even make sense.  Tenure at 40 is a reasonable goal for OP's 22 year-old self starting a new PhD.  Tenure at 40 is completely impossible for OP as it stands.  They likely won't even earn their PhD by that age.

Comment: @ElizabethHenning Again, this is not to say that this isn't the right decision for OP - it could be a brilliant move for them, but as before, it's disingenuous to ignore the fact that such a late start does have a serious impact on career progression.   It's something OP needs to consider carefully for themselves.

Answer (score 5):

Your age is not the thing you should be worrying about. You only have one life and you should be working to live it as you find comfortable, pleasurable, useful, ...

The particular field you think you want to enter now should also be a secondary concern in terms of its "hotness". Whether it actually interests you and you feel it is worth pursuing is a much more important consideration. Your chosen field, whatever it is, will probably have a different "hotness index" when you finish than when you start.

You will be older in a few years whether you do the doctorate or not. If you don't, then where will you be in your life's plan. My former spouse finished a doctorate at about 40 and went on to a nice career. And, of course, a decision made now can be altered somewhere along the line as things, including your own needs, change.

Whether you need to spend time in a post-doc depends on a lot of things. Many people do now-a-days, but a lot of that is just the job market. If it takes you a few years to earn the doctorate then the market is highly likely to be different when you finish than when you start. Unfortunately you can't say whether it will be better or worse then, but that would be true if you were 20, now.

And being on the tenure track in the US (an assistant professor) is really being a professor. You just don't have quite the same job security as a tenured person, but the job is really just the same: Teaching, Research, Service in some proportion depending on the institution.

So, my best advice is to do what most appeals to your sense of self-worth.

Answer (score 5):

Anecdotal evidence:

1. I started in my PhD program at age 40, and now have a permanent faculty position (teaching) in Electrical Engineering.
2. A friend was a little older than me when she started the program, and she is now an Assistant professor in computer science.

Here's what my friend and I found. As I aged, my raw ability to solve problems and memorize things has diminished. In exchange, I am really good at the following: prioritizing my time, presenting, writing, networking, taking initiative, and other important skills. Essentially, even though we're older, we still can have a good package, and other people know it.

Comment: I'd absolutely love to have a conversation with you if that's possible. Would that be okay?

Answer (score 3):

By and large, ageism in academia is *less* pronounced than in many nonacademic fields. In some fields like pure math and theoretical physics, *arguably* there is a bias that young minds do the best work, but even there demonstrated research success overcomes that bias, and I believe it is less in computer science to begin with.

However, age often correlates with greater family responsibilities and less geographic and schedule flexibility. The "two-body problem", navigating the job market, is challenging enough for a couple in their 20s, starting out a life together but (usually, not always) without additional dependents, and a decent tolerance for temporary distance relationships and sleeping on lumpy couches. It then gets more difficult when a move is required (e.g. postdoc to junior tenure track) just as the family unit wants to put down roots.

Since you're about 10 years older, think about how you and those close to you will react when your academic career requires you to move to a different corner of the country when you're, say, 42. Maybe that's not a problem, or maybe your specific qualifications will be enough in demand that you can be choosy, but worth considering how much this will constrain the optimal random walk through academia your career will take.